# Dart: String concatenation error: expected type is 'num'?

Tags: compiler-errors, dart, string-concatenation

In my Dart app I *need* to have a `const` string variable defined like so:

```
library myapp;
part "Lookups.dart";

const String MY_SERVER_URL_PATTERN = "http://%s/" + Lookups.APP_NAME;

// ...more code
```

Where `Lookups.dart` is:

```
part of myapp;

abstract class Lookups {
    static const String APP_NAME = "myapp";
}
```

But I'm getting a compiler error on the `MY_SERVER_URL_PATTERN` declaration:

> An expression of type 'num' was expected.

Why am I getting this, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the `+` operator.
If you rewrite it like

```dart
const String MY_SERVER_URL_PATTERN = "http://%s/${Lookups.APP_NAME}";
```

it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) - do you think I should report it to [dartbug.com](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list) or do you know if it's already in there? Thanks again!

Comment: Please report. I was not aware of this bug and couldn't find an issue.

Comment: ...and done ([#15853](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15853&thanks=15853&ts=1388666708)). I'll make a mental note to try and remember to update this question when this bug gets fixed.